# Correlation Matrix for monthly return streams in Tableau

Tags: excel, matrix, tableau-api, correlation

[image]

Can someone help me create this same thing in Tableau? I am trying to do it for about 20 different stocks. I would appreciate help!

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the CORR() and COVAR() aggregate functions in the [Tableau Documentation](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_aggregate_create.htm) There are also table calculation versions WINDOW_CORR() and WINDOW_COVAR()

To be effective with them, read about the differences between aggregate calculations and table calcs also. One hint, aggregate calculations are performed by the data source (say Postgres or Oracle), table calculations are performed by the client (say Tableau) taking the aggregate query results as input.